# Putting to a Filename named after a variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using `Put (>>)` to store information that I am obtaining in *Mathematica*. The problem is that I am putting a several variables. However, if I do the following, it outputs to a file called `year` rather than my variable.

For example:

```
year=64;
sortedTally>>year;
```

This exports to a file named `year` rather than a file named `64`. The documentation notes that `expr >> filename` is equivalent to `expr >> "filename"`. Is there any way to circumvent this and put to a filename that changes based on the variables? This is similarly reiterated in the documentation file on [Operator Input Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) (at the bottom).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need to use `Put[sortedTally, ToString[year]]`.

Comment: Fantastic. My sincerest thanks for your generous help! I had seen this but had been hung up on the OutputForm documentation. I found the inability to set a variable very confusing - it seemed abnormal for Mathematica.